Navigationsplitview column size change
Is there a way to get the size of an navigationsplitview column size when changing the column size.
I can see that you can put in the size when creating the view but i can't see an way to get the size value when dragging.
I want to use the size change to change to view inside the detail of content view according the column size.
Hope you understand what i want / looking for.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var contentColumnWidth: CGFloat = 250
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(sidebar: {
            Text("Navigation view")
        }, content: {
            Text("Content view")
                .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(contentColumnWidth)
        }, detail: {
            Text("Detail view")
        })
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

Above a simple piece of code for testing purpose.
All this is for macos developing.
